# Powershell - Mix 2 XML files

Tags: xml, powershell, import, export, addition

I already have a look on existing topics and nothing found..
I have 2 XML file, almost identical except some line. 
The aim is to get values from first XML, add it into the 2nd XML and then, the second one will erase the first XML file.

Here is the structure of 1st file

```
<configuration >
<protocol>
 <NATIVE>
 </NATIVE>
 <ICAP>
 </ICAP>
 <RPC>
  <ClientList>
    <items>
      <item value="X.X.X.X">
      <item value="A.A.A.A">
    </items>
  </ClientList>
</configuration>
```

and the second file :

```
<configuration >
<protocol>
 <NATIVE>
 </NATIVE>
 <ICAP>
 </ICAP>
 <RPC>
  <ClientList>
    <items>
      <item value>

    </items>
  </ClientList>
</configuration>
```

The aim is to get the line with "Item Value = ..." and insert it into the 2nd XML files. For all line which could exist

I try to save value into TXT file, and then import it from TXT like this way :

```
$xmlpath1 = "c:\temp\configuration.xml"
$xmlpath2 = "c:\configuration1.xml"
$xmlpath3 = "c:\temp\output.txt"
[xml]$xd= Get-Content $xmlpath1
[xml]$xd2= Get-Content $xmlpath2

$rpc=($xd.configuration.protocol.RPC.ClientList.items.item  )
$rpc2=($xd2.configuration.protocol.RPC.ClientList.items.item  )

foreach($value in $rpc2){

$value.value >> "c:\temp\output.txt"

}
$txt = get-content $xmlpath3 
foreach($line in $txt){
$a=$xd.configuration.protocol.RPC.ClientList.items["item"]
$new=$xd.CreateElement("item")
[void]$a.AppendChild($new)
$a.setattribute("value","$line")
 $xd.Save($xmlpath1)

}
```

but instead of getting :

```
<ClientList>
    <items>
      <item value="X.X.X.X">
        <item value="A.A.A.A"/>
        <item value="B.B.B.B"/>
        <item value="C.C.C.C"/>
      </item>
    </items>
  </ClientList>
```

I got :

```
<ClientList>
    <items>
      <item value="C.C.C.C">     <== Last entry read by PS...
        <item />
        <item />
        <item />

      </item>
    </items>
</ClientList>
```

If tested lot of different ways, but all with not success.
If you have any suggestions it would be great !

Comment: A good start is to provide us with consistent and working xml-samples. The items in your result doesn't match the input files, and the input-files are incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, your files are contains invalid xml, fix them and give this a try.

```
$newXml = @"
<configuration>
<protocol>
<NATIVE></NATIVE>
<ICAP></ICAP>
 <RPC>
  <ClientList>
    <items>
        $(
            $xd.SelectNodes("//configuration/protocol/RPC/ClientList/items").InnerXml
            $xd2.SelectNodes("//configuration/protocol/RPC/ClientList/items").InnerXml
        )
    </items>
  </ClientList>
   </RPC>
   </protocol>
</configuration>
"@

$newXml | Out-File $xmlpath2
Remove-Item $xmlpath1 -Force
```

Comment: Hello

thnx for your reply and discovering of @"...."@. 
Select Node doesn't select anything,  the out file is, except the content of @"..."@, empty.

More, the 2 XML files have 114 lines with lot of settings. My first thought was to include it into a script not dedicated to that.

I will work deeper on SelectNode applet/command
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. It takes all the item elements from the clientlist node in `test1.xml` and adds them to `test2.xml`:

```
$xml1 = [xml](Get-Content .\Desktop\test1.xml)
$xml2 = [xml](Get-Content .\Desktop\test2.xml)

#foreach item-nodes with value attribute in xml1
$xml1.SelectNodes("//configuration/protocol/RPC/ClientList/items/item[@value]") | % { 
    #check if item already exists. If not, add
    if($xml2.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/protocol/RPC/ClientList/items/item[@value='$($_.value)']") -eq $null) {
        $xml2.SelectSingleNode("//configuration/protocol/RPC/ClientList/items").AppendChild($xml2.CreateElement("item")).SetAttribute("value",$_.value)
    }
}

$xml2.Save("C:\Users\graimer\Desktop\test2.xml")
```

I've added the xml files before and after since I had to modify them(close some elements) before they were valid xml.

test1.xml (before)

```
<configuration>
<protocol>
 <NATIVE></NATIVE>
 <ICAP></ICAP>
 <RPC>
  <ClientList>
    <items>
      <item value="X.X.X.X" />
      <item value="A.A.A.A" />
    </items>
  </ClientList>
</RPC>
</protocol>
</configuration>
```

test2.xml (before)

```
<configuration >
<protocol>
 <NATIVE>
 </NATIVE>
 <ICAP>
 </ICAP>
 <RPC>
  <ClientList>
    <items>
    </items>
  </ClientList>
</RPC>
</protocol>
</configuration>
```

test2.xml (after)

```
<configuration>
  <protocol>
    <NATIVE>
    </NATIVE>
    <ICAP>
    </ICAP>
    <RPC>
      <ClientList>
        <items>
          <item value="X.X.X.X" />
          <item value="A.A.A.A" />
        </items>
      </ClientList>
    </RPC>
  </protocol>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Woha. I have still a lot of work to understand exactly how XML and PS works....
YOur script works very well.  The condition is than the XML files must have the same size (number of line, etc... ) 
Thanks a lot ! 
I will work on this

Comment: np ;) if you consider this the correct answer, please use the checkmark to confirm it. I'm not sure what you're saying with the condition. The script above does not require the same filesize, number of lines etc. test1 and test2 can be different, as long as they follow the same scheme and are valid(all elements are closed). It will only modify the clientlist and will make sure that every item in test1 is created in test2 (without creating duplicates).

Comment: I will mark the question as solved :)
I say condition because i had error about that. But evrything is fine. Thanks again